# Is a using-declaration supposed to hide an inherited virtual function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, icc, using-declaration

```
struct level0
{
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct level1 : level0
{
  virtual void foo() { cout <<" level1  " << endl; }
};

struct level2 : level1
{
  virtual void foo() { cout <<" level2 " << endl; }
};

struct level3 : level2
{
  using level1::foo;
};

int main()
{
  level1* l1 = new level3;
  l1->foo();
  level3 l3;
  l3.foo();
  return 0;
}
```

the above code using gcc gives

```
level2
level1
```

but in icc gives

```
 level2
 level2
```

Which one is correct or is it undefined by standard?

Edit:
This proves there is a bug for sure, consider the following main function

```
int main()
{
    level3 l3;
    l3.foo();               // This prints level1

    level3* pl3 = &l3;
    pl3->foo();             // This prints level2

    level3& rl3 = l3;
    rl3.foo();              // This prints level1

    level3& rpl3 = *pl3;
    rpl3.foo();             // This prints level2

    return 0;
}
```

So the same object when used directly produces different results and when used via a pointer of same type produces different results!!!

Comment: I would guess GCC is correct, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've confirmed the behavior with TDM MinGW g++ 4.4.1. It's a g++ bug, please report it. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Funny, I was just looking into this yesterday.

Comment: This was fixed in GCC 4.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example in Standard section 10.3p2 makes it clear that using declarations do *not* override virtual functions.

This is a [known g++ bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11750).

As you noticed, when calling the member function via a reference or pointer, rather than a case in which the dynamic type is known, the bug does not happen.

Comment: +1 for standard quote, as for the bug: reported in 2004, last update in 2006 --> I guess nobody really cares given the easy work around :)

Answer (score 1):

`using level1::foo;` introduces a `foo` function in `level3` class which refers to `level1::foo`.

> In a using-declaration used as a member-declaration, the nested-name-speciﬁer shall name a base class of the class being deﬁned. Such a using-declaration introduces the set of declarations found by member name lookup.

However, since `level1::foo` is virtual, I guess that by calling it you should call `level2::foo`, thus icc should be right.

I'm not so sure, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get level1 level1 of course would be:

```
struct level3 : level2
{
   virtual void foo() { level1::foo(); }
};
```

Your "using" directive seems to be informing the compiler that if you have a level3 and call foo on it, it should invoke the level1 version, but it is not overwriting this to the v-table.

gcc looks wrong because of the inconsistency, not sure about icc because I don't know what the standard indicates.